# Pass data from different events to common callback only when data meets a specific condition

Tags: javascript, promise

I have 2 events: onHeightChanged and onAgeChanged and a callback

```
function onHeightChanged(height){
   // I want to pass height to callback
   callBack(....);
}

function onAgeChanged(age){
   // I want to pass age to callback
   callBack(....);
}

function callBack(height, age){
    if(height > 160 && height< 200 && age > 18 && age < 50){
       allowDriving();
    }
}

function allowDriving(){
   // My code here
}
```

Problem is that, the 2 events onHeightChanged and onAgeChanged occur not in a consistent order (one may before or after another..)
and the 2 values both height and age may range differently.

Any idea on how to collect the later data and the allowDriving function gets called? I think about using promise but I just don't know to realize it
Thank you so much

updated: the 2 events onHeightChanged and onAgeChanged may occur several time thus age and height won't stay the same when passed to callback function

Comment: You need to give more context. Where and How do you call these two functions onHeightChanged and onAgeChanged  ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully understood what you meant by `how to collect the later data and the allowDriving function gets called?`. But still this is what I'd do:

```
function onHeightChanged(height){
   // I want to call allowDriving and pass height to it
   callBack({ height });
}

function onAgeChanged(age){
   // I want to call allowDriving and pass age to it
   callBack({ age });
}

function callBack({ height, age }){
    const isHeightInRange = !age && (height > 160 && height< 200);
    const isAgeInRange = !height && (age > 18 && age < 50);
    if(isHeightInRange || isAgeInRange){ // ---> Here it should be &&, but your business logic doesn't suffice to make it work
       return allowDriving();
    }
}

function allowDriving(){
   // collect users driving data here and maybe store to DB
}
```

^ I don't think your business logic is not that clear. I have written the above code snippet is correlation with your current business logic, in which only either age or height gets passed to `callBack` function from the `onEvent` handlers. Ideally there should be a logic to pass in both height and age and then allow the user to drive.

If it was in React, I would've stored the `age` and `height` in a `state` and would update those states in the `onEvent` handlers, such that I could just check both those states together without any callbacks to `allowDriving`. Maybe a similar approach should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english but I have updated my question. Since age and height constantly change because onHeightChanged and onAgeChanged constantly occur. I just want to proccess other things right after the data is valid. Due to my business, I won't save it to local states and use time interval to read the data.